# finding out the 4th number in a for loop javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this little javascript code, it loops twelve times displaying the the number col, but at the same time I want to console "new row", each time it hits the fourth element:

JS:

```
for(var col= 0; col < 12; col++){
    if((col + 1) % 4 === 0)
      console.log("New Row");

    console.log(col)
}
```

This deosn't seem to work, It consoles "New Row" on the third element, thanks

Comment: You mean array index 4 or the 4th element (array index 3)?  Try getting rid of the ` + 1` if you want the 4th element, starting at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var col= 0; col <= 12; col++){
    if(col % 4 == 0 && col != 0) { // col != 0 to not write "New Row" for first row, if you want on first row remove that condition
      console.log("New Row");
    }

    console.log(col)
}
```

on rows - 4, 8 and 12 it outputs "New Row"

Comment: its funny this is exactly what i wanted thanks!!! @jbabey needs read before you comment. :)

Comment: the code was originally exactly the same, and was edited afterwards to a correct answer - hence the 3 downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Your code outputs "New Row" on the fourth element. The only difference is that col starts from zero:

```
0 <-- first element
1 <-- second element
2 <-- third element
"New Row" <-- fourth element
```

Answer (score 0):

It will log 'New Row' when `col` is `3`.

This is actually the 4th iteration of the loop, as the first time `col` was `0`.

You can also check directly for `col` being equal to 3:

```
col === 3
```

Instead of:

```
(col + 1) % 4 === 0
```